# Gaps between rectangles around an SVG Circle with D3.js is not universal

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I have drawn a `SVG circle` and `rectangles` around that. Now I am drawing `2 rectangles` as a `group`.The `rectangle combo` might be center facing or outside facing. It depends on the `height` of the `rectangle`. The problem I am facing is not able to make the gap between them universal. Its varying while `rectangle` is inside facing or out side facing.

Here is the `jsfiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/xcn35ycm/.  Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You want to have each pair of red/green bars to be parallel? Because right now, they have slightly different angle (off by 5 degrees).

Comment: Yes exactly thats  what I want. each pair to be parallel irrespective of facing towards or outwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since red and green bars have a different angle, you need to adjust this angle when applying the rotation. Your transforming should be something like:

```
.attr('transform', function(d) {
var x = this.getAttribute('x'),
    y = this.getAttribute('y'),
    z = this.getAttribute('key'),
    c = d.color,
    a = (c=='green') ? -5 : 0;
  if(z>=0)
    {
        return "rotate ("+ (d.angle+ang0+a) +" "+ x +" "+ y +")"
    }else{
        return "rotate ("+ (d.angle+a) +" "+ (x) +" "+ (y) +")"
    }
```

See the **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xcn35ycm/1/)**.

A better approach would be to first create actual groups `<svg:g>`and then add the bars within that (rotated) group because the base of the bars in each pair are still slightly off due to the calculation of the coordinates based on the different angles.

You would need to alter your data object to have both red and green values for a group in one set. Next, alter your script to first "draw" the groups and then append the bars. See this snippet for an example:

```js
var squares = [
  {angle: 45, color1: 'red', height1:-55, key1:-55, color2: 'green', height2:25, key2:25},
  {angle: 90, color1: 'red', height1:50, key1:50, color2: 'green', height2:-30, key2:-30},
  {angle: 135, color1: 'red', height1:35, key1:35, color2: 'green', height2:55, key2:55},
  {angle: 180, color1: 'red', height1:10, key1:10, color2: 'green', height2:30, key2:30},
  {angle: 225, color1: 'red', height1:75, key1:75, color2: 'green', height2:15, key2:15},
  {angle: 270, color1: 'red', height1:15, key1:15, color2: 'green', height2:15, key2:15},
  {angle: 315, color1: 'red', height1:25, key1:25, color2: 'green', height2:25, key2:25},
  {angle: 360, color1: 'red', height1:55, key1:55, color2: 'green', height2:55, key2:55},
];
var x0 = 190, y0 = 190, r= 100, w = 10, h= 55, ang0 = 180;
var combos = d3.select('svg').selectAll("g").data(squares)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr({width: 2 * w})
    .attr('height', function (d) {
   return Math.max(d.height1, d.height2) + r;
  })
    .attr('x', function (d) {
      return x0;
    })
    .attr('y', function (d) {
      return y0;
    })
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
     return 'rotate(' + (d.angle + ang0) + ', ' + x0 + ', ' + y0 + ') translate(' + x0 + ', ' + y0 + ')';
   });
combos.append("rect")
    .attr({width: w})
    .attr('x', -w)
    .attr('y', function(d) {
     return d.height1 < 0 ? r + d.height1 : r;
    })
    .attr('height', function (d) {
      return Math.abs(d.height1);
    })
    .attr('key', function (d) {
      return d.key1;
    })
    .attr('fill', function(d) {
     return d.color1; 
     });
     
combos.append("rect")
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', function(d) {
     return d.height2 < 0 ? r + d.height2 : r;
    })
    .attr({width: w})
    .attr('height', function (d) {
      return Math.abs(d.height2);
    })
    .attr('key', function (d) {
      return d.key2;
    })
    .attr('fill', function(d) {
     return d.color2; 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width='400' height='400'>
   <circle cx='190' cy='190' r='100' fill='none' stroke='red'></circle>
</svg>
```

To simplify your script, I did a couple of changes. For example, no need to calculate x and y coordinates using the angle if you just center your transformation on the circles center. Only change required for the group and the bars is to add the radius. Also available as a **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xcn35ycm/2/)**.

Comment: Thanks @Paul for the reply. Could you please provide me  a jsfiddle for that. Because the same problem exists with me also. I can manage them while both are facing outward or inward. But for either facing inward or outward its not working

Comment: I already included a fiddle for the above solution, click on the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xcn35ycm/1/) link in my answer. To achieve the proposed better approach, you would eventually need to alter your data object to have both green and red values in one set. You would then create a group for each set and append the bars to that group.

Comment: Yeh actually I was looking for a fiddle for the better approach. I can change my data as its upto me. But not sure how you want me to change the format and how to create the group.Hence asked for a fiddle

Comment: I added a snippet with what I assume to be your desired result.

Comment: Looks Cool @Paul , I will check and accept your answer.Thanks for the help